# Intersystems caché - read variable in global using .net - c#

Tags: c#, odbc, intersystems-cache

Is there any way how to get all data from global stored in intersystems caché db using .net/c# without ObjectScript method in caché? I have these data in global, for example:

```
^myGlob("x","y","Dta",1)    =   "Test 1"
^myGlob("x","y","Dta",2)    =   "Test 2"
^myGlob("cfg","sd") =   "Cfg test 1";
```

Is it possible to access this data directly using .net? Can I execute caché query from c# without ObjectScript method calling?

(I want to do it via ODBC, but i need to access to another globals with different global name and indexes name, so i need to define data structure in runtime)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it only in .Net, with Caché eXTreme
Example from [documentation](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20141/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=BXNT_globals).

```
using System;
using InterSystems.Globals;

class FetchNodes {
  public static void Main(String[] args) {
    Connection myConn = ConnectionContext.GetConnection();
    try {
      myConn.Connect("User", "_SYSTEM", "SYS");
      NodeReference nodeRef = myConn.CreateNodeReference("myGlobal");
      // Read both existing nodes
      Console.WriteLine("Value of ^myGlobal is " + nodeRef.GetString());
      Console.WriteLine("Value of ^myGlobal(\"sub1\") is " + nodeRef.GetString("sub1"));
      nodeRef.Kill();   // delete entire array
      nodeRef.Close();
      myConn.Close();
    }
    catch (GlobalsException e) { Console.WriteLine(e.Message); }
  } // end Main()
} // end class FetchNodes
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But where can i found Intersystems.Globals class? I have accessible only InterSystems.Data. Do I use bad library? Can you help me?

Comment: Which version of Caché do you use ?

Comment: dev\dotnet\bin\v4.0.30319\InterSystems.CacheExtreme.dll

Comment: Thanks. I am afraid caché version will be my problem. I use Cache for Windows (x86-64) 2011.1.2 (Build 701U). Your code will work on caché 2012 and higher, isn't it? I don't have InterSystems.CacheExtreme.dll in my cahé install folder.

Comment: Yes, .Net eXTreme have appeared only in 2012.2. I'm not sure but you can try to use newest library with this functionality for your version. Maybe it will work.

Comment: Ok, I can't found InterSystems.CacheExtreme.dll for download. Do you know where can I found it? Or do you have idea if any similar approach to solve this issue exist?

Comment: If You have an access to WRC, you can download any version, and last pre-release version 2015.1. If not, also possible to download evaluation version   from intersystems site http://www.intersystems.com/library/software-downloads/

Comment: I'm not sure about any other possibilities for so old version.